# law of absolute of max of brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, distribution

What is the law of $\max\left(|B_t|\right)$ for $t$ in $[0,T]$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion?
Any references for properties of this process?

Comment: Define $M(T):=\max_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B(t)|.$ Then

$P(M(T)>a) = 2P(B(t)>a)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi T}} \int_a^\infty e^{-x^2/2T}dx.$

You can see the proof in Stochastic calculus for finance II from Shreve or just look for the reflection principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)

Comment: Yep. Reflected Brownian motion and a passage time; standard stuff.

Comment: The reflection principle argument only works for the running maximum itself ($\max W_t$) and not the maximum of the absolute value $\max |W_t|$.

Comment: c.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356903/running-maximum-absolute-value-of-wiener-process/1077795